# GetElementById not working when attracting an ID with hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using attr('id') on an unchangeable id tag for a html element, my code works fine for all instances where the id has no hyphens, however breaks when the id does include a hyphen.

```
$('.coloursContainer .radio-box').live('click', function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){

    } else {
        var radioID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).parent().find('.radio-box').removeClass('selected');
        document.getElementById(radioID).classList.add('selected');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="coloursContainer">
    <div class="radio-box" id="Natural Wave Structure" data-category="trim-colour" data-price="0">
        <span class="selectedSign">SELECTED</span>
        <span class="imgBox" style="background-image:url('/img/colours/804.jpg')"></span>
        <h3>Natural Wave Structure</h3>
        <p>+ £0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-box" id="Semi-solid Oak" data-category="trim-colour" data-price="0">
        <span class="selectedSign">SELECTED</span>
        <span class="imgBox" style="background-image:url('/img/colours/203.jpg')"></span>
        <h3>Semi-solid Oak</h3>
        <p>+ £0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first radio box has the 'selected' class added, however the second box with ID "Semi-solid Oak" does not.

Comment: html id attribute must not contain whitespace. Your problem is not the hypnen it is the space

Comment: **Aside note:** Your code is using a mix of technologies as well as old functions.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou add that as the answer

Comment: you have invalid id's . They should be unique, singular and not consist of characters separated by space. Also for the jQuery part : `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. `

Comment: Using jQuery 1.7, the code works fine as-is: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a9go5erz/

Comment: Fixed version using current jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dm7uoy1b/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem from jquery version you use and i think this can be fixed with using `.on` instead `.live.` Check jquery  Documentation http://api.jquery.com/live/[Check jquery  Documentation][1]

Answer (score 0):

HTML `id` attribute must not contain whitespace. You have invalid HTML and that causes JavaScript to not find your id.

As a side note you are using the old `live` function and you are mixing jQuery with vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.coloursContainer .radio-box').on('click', function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){

    } else {
        var radioID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).parent().find('.radio-box').removeClass('selected');
       // document.getElementById(radioID).classList.add('selected');
       $("[id='"+radioID+"']").addClass( "selected" );

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coloursContainer">
<div class="radio-box" id="Natural Wave Structure" data-category="trim-colour" data-price="0">
<span class="selectedSign">SELECTED</span>
<span class="imgBox" style="background-image:url('/img/colours/804.jpg')"></span>
<h3>Natural Wave Structure</h3>
<p>+ £0</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-box" id="Semi-solid Oak" data-category="trim-colour" data-price="0">
<span class="selectedSign">SELECTED</span>
<span class="imgBox" style="background-image:url('/img/colours/203.jpg')"></span>
<h3>Semi-solid Oak</h3>
<p>+ £0</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I have modified your code.